# Mean of a Binomial Probability Distribution?

Tags: probability

Consider the Binomial Probability Distribution:

$$P(X=k) = \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$

I know that from first principles, the Expected Value of this distribution is $np$, that is $E(X) = np$. **I am trying to understand why this is true.**

I know that since the Binomial Distribution is a discrete distribution, we can write the Expected Value as:

$$E(X) = \sum x_i *p(x_i)$$
$$E(X) = \sum x_i * \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$

**But I am not sure how I can use these facts to show that the Expected Value equals to $np$**

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks!

**Note:** Is it also possible to calculate a closed form solution to

$$E(X) = \sum x_i^{2} * \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$

Comment: Hint: Expand $k\binom{n}{k}$ and see if you can rewrite it to be useful.

Comment: @SeanRoberson : thank you for your reply! I will try doing this!

Comment: By far the easiest way is to identify binomial as a sum of bernoullis. Otherwise, there are some tricks you can do. See grimmett and stirzaker's text for details

Comment: Btw, the expected value is $$E(X) = \sum_{k=0}^n k\cdot \binom{n}{k} \cdot p^k \cdot (1-p)^{n-k}$$

Comment: @Andrew: thank you for this reference!

Comment: @callculus42: thank you for this correction!

Comment: @stats_noob Hoping that you was able to calculate the expected valuel.

Comment: Hi everyone - I think I was able to solve my own question. Can you please take a look at my answer and let me know if I was correct? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good to be able to do the calculations. It's also good to know other ways to get the answer, so here is one.

A variable with binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$ is equivalent to the sum of $n$ independent Bernoulli variables with parameter $p$ (variables that have value $1$ with probability $p$, $0$ otherwise). This models the number of heads in $n$ tosses of a (possibly unfair) coin. You might even say this is the motivation for the definition of the binomial distribution.

To see why the sum of $n$ i.i.d. Bernoulli variables and the binomial distribution are equivalent, let $X$ be the number of heads in $n$ tosses of a coin that comes up heads with probability $p$ and consider the probability that you have exactly $k$ heads.
(That is, $k$ "success" outcomes in $n$ Bernoulli variables with parameter $p$.)
Any particular sequence of $k$ heads and $k - 1$ tails has probability
$p^k (1 - p)^{n - k}$, and there are $\Large\binom nk$ sequences of $k$ heads and $n - k$ tails. Therefore
$$
P(X = k) = \binom nk p^k (1 - p)^{n - k},
$$
so $X$ has a binomial distribution by definition.

So we can define $n$ i.i.d. Bernoulli variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$
such that $P(X_i) = p$, and then $X = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n$
has a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$.

The expected value (mean) of the Bernoulli variable $X_i$ is $p$.
By the linearity of expectation, the expected value of the sum of the $n$
Bernoulli variables (that is, the expected value of $X$)
is the sum of their expected values,
$$
E(X) = E(X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n) = E(X_1) + \cdots + E(X_n) = np.
$$

As a bonus of this method of proof, we also have a formula for the distribution of a sum of Bernoulli variables, which is often the source of a binomial distribution.

Comment: Thank you so much for your elegant response! I really like the simplicity of this! I posted a question over here - can you please take a look at it if you have time? thank you so much! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4759114/comparing-maximum-likelihood-estimation-vs-method-of-moments

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to solve my own problem.

The Binomial Distribution is defined as:

$$P(X=k) = \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$

And from first principles, the Expected Value of the Binomial Distribution can be written as:

$$E(X) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} k * \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$

Note that this sum can be written from $k=1$ , since $k=0$ makes no contribution to this sum:

$$E(X) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k * \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$

Now, let's open the Binomial Coefficient :

$$E(X) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k * \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$

Now for some simplifications - remember that we can write $10!$ as $10 * 9!$. This means that we can write $n! =  n*(n-1)!$ and $k! =  k*(k-1)!$ . Using this information, we can re-write the above term as:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k * \frac{n(n-1)!}{k(k-1)!(n-k)!} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$

We can see that the first $k$ and the $k$ in the denominator cancel out. Also note that $p^k$ can be written as $p*p^{k-1}$. So now, we can write:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!} p* p^{k-1} (1-p)^{n-k}$$

We can see an $np$ in the above term that is not contributing to the sum - therefore, we can take it outside:

$$n*p \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!} * p^{k-1} (1-p)^{n-k}$$

Now, let define a new variable $y = k-1$. This means that we can re-write the above expression as:

$$n*p \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(n-1)!}{(y)!(n-y-1)!} * p^{y} (1-p)^{n-y-1}$$

Next, we can see that $\frac{(n-1)!}{(y)!(n-y-1)!}$ is in the form of a Binomial Coefficient $\binom{n-1}{y}$. So now, we can write:

$$n*p \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n-1}{y} * p^{y} (1-p)^{n-y-1}$$

And finally, we can notice that the summation term is of the form: $(a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} a^k b^{n-k}$ . Using this logic, we can write the above term as:

$$ np * (p+1-p)^{n-1}$$
$$np *1^{n-1} = np*1 =  np$$

Thus, we have shown that

$$E(X) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} k * \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} = np $$

Am I correct?